# Portainer Unable To Connect Local Docker Server

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, portainer

im trying to using portainer on my docker in windows using vs2022 micro-service Architecture here is my docker-compose config :

```
services:
portainer:
  image: portainer/portainer-ce
```

volumes:
portainer_data:

and this is my docker-compose.override.yml

```
portainer: 
container_name: portainer
restart: always
ports:
 - "8080:8000"
 - "9000:9000"
volumes:
 - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
 - /mnt/Docker-Data/portainer:/data
```

and update docker containers using this command on developer-powershell

docker-compose -f .\docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml  up -d

i started portainer on port:9000
but it's not connected to local docker !!